# Change one file of merge request without raising a new merge request

Tags: git, gitlab, merge-request

I did some changes in dev branch , committed and pushed (`git push origin dev`)and created a new merge request from gitlab frontend . But now i want to modify 1 file in same merge request without raising new one . Can I delete dev branch on remote and change that file on local, commit  and push again as `git push origin dev` . Will this harm my current merge request ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I still add commit on branch after created merge request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58046505/can-i-still-add-commit-on-branch-after-created-merge-request)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that modification should be part of your MR (Merge Request), you can simply commit on your MR branch (dev), and push: that will update your MR.

If it is *not* part of your MR, you should create a new branch from dev, commit there and push that new branch.

Comment: Yes , I did you are mentioning but getting below error : `hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
`

Comment: @PrashantSingh Are other developers contributing to dev as well? Or are you the only one pushing to it?

Comment: Only i am pushing or using  dev branch and it needs to to be merged in master branch .

Comment: @PrashantSingh If your local history for `dev` branch is correct, you can `git push --force` to the remote: it will update the remote `dev` branch and your MR as well, since your MR was raised from `dev`.

Comment: so doing `git push --force` will update the branch content. And the link https://dummy.com/backend/-/merge_requests/662 of that MR will not change , right ? Basically I don't want to raise another MR and again send mail to manager , since I have already given him the link https://dummy.com/backend/-/merge_requests/662 .

Comment: @PrashantSingh Yes, the link will not change, but its content will, if you did raise the MR 662 from the dev branch. Updating that dev branch will update MR 662 (without changing its link)

Comment: I first thought that the MR is a new entity apart from the branch, but if you commit to the branch and push you will automatically update the MR with that.